# How to show the result of command read in emacs's shell mode?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

Version info:

- GNU Emacs 25.1.1
- GNOME Terminal 3.20.2

The command `read -ei "hi"` will show a result `hi` in gnome-terminal(bash), but will not show the result `hi` in emacs's shell mode(M-x shell).

From Paul's answer:

`read -ei "hi"` and `C-m` in gnome-terminal(bash) will show:

```
[d@localhost Desktop]$ read -ei "hi"
hi
```

`read -ei "hi"` and `C-m` in emacs's shell mode will show:

```
[d@localhost Desktop]$ read -ei "hi"
```

What I expect to see in emacs's shell mode:

```
[d@localhost Desktop]$ read -ei "hi"
hi
```

So how to show the result of command `read` in emacs's shell mode?

Comment: `read -e "hi" && $REPLY` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @BenjaminW. My fault. Edited now.

Comment: It still makes no sense. It tries to run the input as a command. It only shows "hi" because the input is pre-populated. Does emacs shell mode support readline?

Comment: It doesn't even seem to have a `read` command: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html

Comment: @BenjaminW. `eshell` is the elisp shell, shell-mode is just a wrapper around a regular shell

Comment: I found that I misunderstood `read` and `$REPLY`, so my old question was not correct. Edit now :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding an echo:

```
read -ei "hi" && echo $REPLY
```

Comment: showing what you see and what you expect to see would be helpful

Comment: Thank you Paul. I found that I misunderstood `read` and `$REPLY`, so my old question was not correct. Edit now :)